# Time complexity of given code

Tags: c++, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this code which swap `a[i,j]` with `a[j,i]` for `j > i` (transpose the given matrix):

```
for(i=1;i<=(n-1);i++)
{
    for(j=(i+1);j<=n;j++)
    {
        T=a[i,j];

        a[i,j]=a[j,i];

        a[j,i]=T;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think? How did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: A nice and easy tutorial - http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=complexity1

Comment: The syntax of the swapping is wrong and obviously nobody even noticed it. That's what you get when you do this manually, instead of just calling `std::swap()`.

Comment: Maybe I'll sound stupid but... shouldn't it be `a[i][j]` ? Does the other syntax even work ?

Comment: @ereOn: Yes, that, too, is wrong. And I, too, missed it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if we're willing to assume that whatever goes on in the inner loop is constant time. This being C++, it is impossible to know what that is without knowing the types involved. `a` could support that syntax for 2-D lookup if `i` and `j` are some UDT with an evil comma operator overload that returns a pair, and `a` has a corresponding `operator[]`.

Answer (score 8):

The inner loop does decreasing work from n to 1, and the actual work being done (swapping numbers) is O(1), so:

n operations + (n - 1) operations + (n - 2) operations + ... + 2 operations + 1 operation = sum(1, n) operations = (n * (n + 1)) / 2 = (n<sup>2</sup> + n) / 2 = **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=1;i<=(n-1);i++) { 
    for(j=(i+1);j<=n;j++) { 
        T=a[i,j];
        a[i,j]=a[j,i];
        a[j,i]=T; 
    } 
}
```

The time complexity is O(n^2).